# Handling if-else condition statement on export default and HOC in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How would you handle `export default` in a conditional statement if you have a HOC wrapping a function?

Initial setup:

```
async function subHandler(params, request) {
  ...
}

export default handlerWrap(subHandler);
```

---

I wanted to check a request path of the subHandler, and if path exists, export default something else, something like this:

```
async function subHandler(params, request) {
  ...
}

if (request.path === "somepath") {
  export default subHandler
} else {
  export default handlerWrap(subHandler);
}
```

But i know request is only within the function, so I was hoping someone can help me with this logic

Comment: `const toExport = request.path === "somepath" ? subHandler : handlerWrap(subHander);

export default toExport` or just have a wrapper function to conditionally return ? and export default that function?

Comment: the problem is `request.path` is coming from `function subHandler`. How do you get the request within the `subHandler` and then use it as a condition outside of it for the export?

Comment: check below... I hope that solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return 2 different functions. You can just do what you want to do conditionally inside one function

```
export default async subHandler(params, request) {
   if(request.path === "somepath") {
          return requestHandler;
   }

   return handlerWrap(requestHandler);
}
```

Comment: on a side note general preference is not to use default export. https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2019/01/stop-using-default-exports-javascript-module/